# Handle individual permissions for users in SharePoint hosted app

Tags: 2013, permissions, sharepoint-hosted-app

How can developer handle individual's permissions on SharePoint hosted app? Let's says we have a document library and each user can only see there own documents. Not other users documents.

Comment: Title and description are bit confusing ......